# When are Google Guava EventBus objects garbage collected?

Tags: java, guava

I have a web application that spawns a great many background worker threads in response to requests to a certain endpoint. To allow greater transparency in to the state of the workers, I've added an event bus that the workers can post events to. The events are pushed in to a map, tracking the state of each worker over time. Periodically, the map is snapshotted and pushed to a more permanent location, where the snapshots are associated with the request via a request token.

It certainly is appealing to give each request its own event bus. Then each request gets its own map. When the request completes and the final snapshot is pushed, the map and the event bus go out of scope and are, consequently, garbage collected.

At least, that is the theory. But some people I've talked to have suggested the event bus won't be collected even when the only explicit reference to it goes out of scope, because it manages to create other references for itself during setup. I would really appreciate a more experienced Java/Guava practitioner's perspective.

Comment: I couldn't find anything like that in the documentation.... :-| Are your sources credible?

Comment: I have also seen Threads not been released as soon as the event is handled. Would appreciate any comments on that.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing that prevents `EventBus` objects from being garbage collected when there are no more references to them. You can take a look at the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.java).

What they *may* be referring to is the fact that `EventBus` has a couple of `static` caches that are shared between `EventBus` instances. Those won't be garbage collected. The caches do two things:

- `EventBus.flattenHierarchyCache` keeps a map of classes (the types of the events your subscriber methods subscribe to) to the set of all classes and interfaces each of those classes extends or implements.
- `AnnotatedSubscriberFinder.subscriberMethodsCache` keeps a map of classes (your classes that have subscriber methods) to the methods on those classes that are annotated with `@Subscribe`.

The size of these caches is constrained by the number of different types of events you post to each `EventBus` and the number of different classes you register with each `EventBus`. So, for example, if you're only posting one type of event and you only have one class that you register with your event buses, the caches will be tiny and will stay that way.